# Convenience initializers for custom uiview loaded from .xib

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Is there a way to add convenience initialisers to a custom UIView loaded from a nib?

For example this gist covers the common init method but doesn't have any convenience initializers. I have a few properties that I'd like to set in my custom UIView on initialization.

https://gist.github.com/bwhiteley/049e4bede49e71a6d2e2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you want to override is `awakeFromNib` (called after initialization) or `viewDidLoad` (called after the view is loaded). In most cases it's easier to place initialization in `viewDidLoad`. Your convenience initializers won't be called if you're loaded from a nib (initialization is done by `init(coder:)` in that case).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how/where I can pass in values for the initialisation though? I could of course create the custom view and then call another method to set certain values but can I combine those?

Comment: Where would you be passing the values from? Nibs are loaded by the system; you don't initialize any of those objects. You cannot pass values during the initialization of the view. You can only pass set properties once the view is loaded (generally from its controller).